# Inciar un RDC de forma interactiva de forma programada

Tags: windows, servidor, powershell

tengo un script en powershell para iniciar sesion en un RDC. Este script introduce las credenciales y todo y me deja el escritorio de la máquina virtual listo para usar

Necesito que este script lo ejecute otra maquina virtual desde las tareas programadas, pero al paracer el programador de tareas de windows no me ejcuta este script de forma interactiva (es decir, que se vea como se abre el RDP y todo esto)

Alguien tiene alguna idea de como solucionarlo??

Muchas gracias!

---

Buenas este es mi script:

```
function AS400_RDP{
    param (
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=0)] [string]$server
            )  

$server = Resolve-Path $server
[xml]$ConfigFile = Get-Content -Path $server -Encoding UTF8

$Username1     = $ConfigFile.Settings.General.USERNAME
$Password1     = $ConfigFile.Settings.General.PASSWORD
$keyfile       = $ConfigFile.Settings.General.KEYFILE
$computerName1 = $ConfigFile.Settings.General.COMPUTERNAME

#Resolvemos las rutas
$KeyFile = Resolve-Path $KeyFile

#Creamos Credenciales
$Username = "$Username1"
$Password = "$Password1"
$computerName = "$computerName1"

#Creamos el objeto PSCredential
$key = Get-Content $KeyFile
$credential = New-Object -TypeName  System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
                     -ArgumentList $Username, ($Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key)

#Iniciamos EL RDP
Import-module .\Connect-Mstsc.ps1
Connect-Mstsc -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $credential -w 1024 -h 768
}

AS400_RDP -server C:\Ruta\archivo\XML\CON_DATOS\CONEXION.xml
```

El otro script que importa es es este:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Connect-Mstsc-Open-RDP-2064b10b

En el XML paso la ip del servidor, el usuario, la clave encriptada, y la ruta del archivo .key para desencriptarla

Comment: Podrias mostrar el script?

Comment: Ya lo tienes, Levi Arista

Comment: Listo ya lo agregué a tu pregunta, para agregar información a tu pregunta debes editarla, no usar la sección de preguntas. Mas bien elimina la respuesta. Saludos

Comment: @JoséPabloMedinaGrande Stack Overflow no es un foro donde vas publicando respuestas formando una conversación, es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas (Q&A) donde por un lado hay una pregunta y por otro están las respuestas. Por favor, no uses las respuestas para añadir información adicional o poner cosas que deberían ir en los comentarios. Completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el funcionamiento básico del sitio (y así ganar una nueva medalla) y lee [ask] para más información.